# How do I know if a given path is valid, regardless of the existence or absence of a file in there?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, path, synchronization

I'm starting with NodeJS, and I've looked for the answer in here but haven't found anything useful yet. I have a function that receives a path and needs to check first whether that path is valid, whether a file or directory exists there in the end or not.
My program needs to be sync, I need to check first whether the path received is valid, then if the file exists.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699599/node-js-check-if-file-exists)

Comment: What do you mean by *valid*? Can you show an example of invalid path?

Comment: You don't, because it is a race. Right after you check that the path exists, I can giggle and sneak in and rename one of the directories in the path.

Comment: The operating system does the required synchronization when it is traversing the path. You just open it. How do you create a directory if it maybe exists? You just create it, and expect an EEXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

If by valid you mean following the rules of path syntax, then what you need is to check using a regular expression. An example is:

```js
console.log(/^(\/?[a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)+$/.test('/dir1/dir2')); // true
console.log(/^(\/?[a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)+$/.test('/dir1/dir2//')); // false
```

`/^(\/?[a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)+$/` is the regular expression, this regex matches strings like /a/b/c. You can find more about regex [here](https://regexone.com/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet), [here](https://regex101.com/) instead you can test regex.
Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030285/regex-for-file-path-validation-in-javascript) you can find examples of regex for windows paths.